# Remove password from protected folder c#

Tags: c#, directory

I created a form that has the option of adding and removing a password to a folder. I add the password by selecting it from a table using a datagridview. The code I use to do this is:

```
DirectorySecurity ds = Directory.GetAccessControl(vfld);
FileSystemAccessRule fsa = new FileSystemAccessRule(envusr, FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Deny);
ds.AddAccessRule(fsa);
Directory.SetAccessControl(vfld, ds);
```

`vfld` is a variable that holds the folder string to get the password and envusr is variable that has a value of `Environment.UserName`. This puts the password on with no problem. However when I use the code:

```
DirectorySecurity ds = Directory.GetAccessControl(vfld);
FileSystemAccessRule fsa = new FileSystemAccessRule(envusr, FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Deny);
ds.RemoveAccessRule(fsa);
Directory.SetAccessControl(vfld, ds);
```

To remove the password I get the error message on the line `DirectorySecurity ds = Directory.GetAccessControl(vfld);` saying:

> 'Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.'

Why am I getting this error message if I'm logged into my computer as the same user when I added the password and try to remove it?

Can any one help me here? I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Under what account is the process running? It might need elevated administrative rights.

Comment: Under an Administrator account. It's the only account on the computer.

Comment: `FileSystemAccessRule(envusr, FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Deny);` Remember that deny permissions take precedence over allow. That is to say, if you deny Full Control to a user, they can no longer do anything with that folder, even if they have other "Allow" permissions.

Comment: So is there any way to give them full control again? would I have to be logging into the computer as a different user with equal or higher permission rights?